# Build QT program for linux target from windows

Tags: qt

Is it possible to build app from windows for linux target?

Also, is it possible to debug linux target with windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You may install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) on Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update and later). Any Linux distribution available from the Microsoft Store would be adequate. Then, add the development environment (compilers, development libraries) to you Linux subsystem, and you may build your project for Linux using the bash shell. This would be only slightly more comfortable than installing a Linux virtual machine, but with the inconvenience that GUI programs don't run in WSL. For running and debugging you will need a virtual machine.

Comment: You can run Linux programs from WSL by installing a X server on your Windows system.